# locking rows on rails update to avoid collisions. (Postgres back end)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-models

So I have a method on my model object which creates a unique sequence number when a binary field in the row is updated from null to true.  Its implemented like this:

```
class AnswerHeader < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :update_survey_complete_sequence, if: :survey_complete_changed?

  def update_survey_complete_sequence
    maxval =AnswerHeader.maximum('survey_complete_sequence')
    self.survey_complete_sequence=maxval+1
  end
end
```

My question is what do I need to lock so two rows being updated at the same time don't end up with two rows having the same survey_complete_sequence?

If it is possible to lock a single row rather than whole table that would be good because this is a often accessed table by users.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't create a Postgres sequence and let the DB handle it?

Comment: I could I guess, but I don't like spreading the application logic all over the place (i.e. some in the rails app, some in the DB itself, etc.).  Seems like a maintenance headache.

Comment: PS to anybody who has an answer I don't need really need a "credible source" I just need a solution that works.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to handle this in application logic itself, instead of letting database handle this. You make make use of rails with_lock function that will **create a transaction** and **acquire a row level db lock** on the selected rows(in your case a single row).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should give advisory locks a look. It makes sure the same block of code isn't executed on two machines simultaneously, while still keeping the table open for other business.

It uses the database, but it doesn't lock your tables.

You can use the gem called "with_advisory_lock" like this:

```
Model.with_advisory_lock("ADVISORY_LOCK_NAME") do
  # Your code
end
```

https://github.com/ClosureTree/with_advisory_lock

It doesn't work with SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

**What you need to lock**

In your case you have to lock the row containing the maximum `survey_complete_sequence`, since this is the row every query will look for while getting the value you require.

```
maxval =AnswerHeader.maximum('survey_complete_sequence')
```

**Is it possible to lock a single row rather than whole table**

There is no such specific lock for your scenario. But you can make use of Postgresql's `SELECT FOR UPDATE` [row-level locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/explicit-locking.html).

> To acquire an exclusive row-level lock on a row without actually
>   modifying the row, select the row with SELECT FOR UPDATE.

And you can use [pessimistic locking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html) in rails and specify which lock you will use.

> Call lock('some locking clause') to use a database-specific locking
>   clause of your own such as 'LOCK IN SHARE MODE' or 'FOR UPDATE NOWAIT'

Here's an example of how to achieve that from rails official guide itself

```
Item.transaction do
  i = Item.lock("LOCK IN SHARE MODE").find(1)
  ...
end
```

> Relations using lock are usually wrapped inside a transaction for preventing deadlock conditions.

So what you need doing is -

1. Apply `SELECT FOR UPDATE` lock to row consisting `maximum('survey_complete_sequence')`
2. Get the value you require from that row
3. Update your `AnswerHeader` with the value received

Comment: The row lock will not help him. Even if the row is locked his application will read the maxval from that row or any other.

Comment: The application will only get the value if the lock is successful, when used like this `AnswerHeader.lock('SELECT FOR UPDATE').maximum('survey_complete_sequence')`. Are you saying something else? Or what I said is not what's happening?

Comment: So if he locks row Y that contains the current maximum_value, how does that prevent two parallel threads from reading this maximum_value from X or Y and attempting to create two different rows with the same maximum_value or maximum_value-1 or maximum_value +1? Sorry if I don't understand correctly.

Comment: Suppose two concurrent threads X and Y are searching the database for a maximum `survey_complete_sequence`. Now at that instant if they find a maximum value, it will be the __same row__ for both the threads. So when they both try to read the value, first they are attempting to lock the row with the `SELECT_FOR_UPDATE` mode. Now say X got the locking first, that would mean Y to wait, until the lock is released, to apply the **same lock**, which would prevent it from reading it. So now X will do its remaining job. When the transaction completes, X releases the lock, then Y will do its job.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using postgress, maybe [Sequenced](https://github.com/djreimer/sequenced) can help you out without defining a sequence at the DB level.

Is there a reason survey_complete_sequence should be incremental? if not, maybe randomize a bigint?

Comment: He needs the maximum value which is incremented on each update to the table. A random bigint won't help, nor locking rows or the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to lock the table, and even if you lock the row you're currently updating the row you're basing your maxval on will be available for another update to read and generate its sequence #.

Unless you have a huge table and lots of updates every millisecond (in the order of thousands) this shouldn't be an issue in real life. But if the idea bothers you, you can go ahead and add an unique index to the table on "survey_complete_sequence" column. The DB error will propagate to a Rails exception you can deal with within the application.